# Повторяющиеся номера в SQL

Tags: php, sql

Господа, подскажите, как сделать без повторений? Делаю стандартно так:

```
$l4 = date("H")-4;
$l2 = date("Y-m-d ${l4}:i:s");
    $sql="SELECT  `src` FROM `cdr` WHERE `dcontext` LIKE '%taxi%'  AND calldate >='$l2'";
```

Выходит

```
89522975049
89522975049
89522975049
88452761100
88152445435
```

Пробую

```
SELECT  `src` FROM `cdr` WHERE `dcontext` LIKE '%taxi%'  AND calldate >='$l2'" GROUP BY 'src';
```

Выходит только  этот номер

```
89522975049
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

попробуйте

```
SELECT DISTINCT `src` FROM `cdr` WHERE `dcontext` LIKE '%taxi%'  AND calldate >='$l2'
```

Comment: супер !  большое спасибо

Answer (score 1):

GROUP BY тоже будет работать, если правильно написать:

```
SELECT  `src` FROM `cdr` WHERE `dcontext` LIKE '%taxi%'  AND calldate >='$l2' GROUP BY `src`";
```